# How to create a virtual directory in apache (MAMP) to external HDD?

Tags: apache, mamp

I want to create a "files" virtual directory in my local apache webserver that will point to my external HDD "/Volumes/Iomega_HDD/files".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a symlink:

ln -s /Volumes/Iomega_HDD/files /var/www/files

This would create a link called files, that points at your external volume.

Caveat: Permissions have to be set properly on your /Volumes/Iomega_HDD/files dir to be viewable.